# Combination of Nominatim Openstreetmap Service and Tom MacWright's leaflet leaflet-knn

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet, knn, nominatim

I'd like to combine these tools: [Leaflet control search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search), [leaflet-knn](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn) and [leaflet routing machine](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine).

The first one will get me a point over the street I searched for and the second one will find its closest neighbour. The final step is to navigate using leaflet routing machine.

After the first step I need to find how to use the point's coordinates (the one over the street I mentioned before) in order to complete the knn search (to find the closest neighbour)and finally navigate to it (to the closest neighbour)

I've got a js fiddle but I'm not sure I used it right:
https://jsfiddle.net/mbatsaris/xfcs77wm/
and this json file also.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
var camps = [
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 748287.576139, "Y": 4187057.960012, "aa": 15299, "onoma": "3ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.134146, "lat": 38.377453 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.134146, 38.377453 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 748287.576139, "Y": 4187057.960012, "aa": 15300, "onoma": "11ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.136081, "lat": 38.368424 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.136081, 38.368424 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 748287.576139, "Y": 4187057.960012, "aa": 15301, "onoma": "4ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.134146, "lat": 38.377453 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.134146, 38.377453 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 685890.486674, "Y": 4246925.893043, "aa": 15152, "onoma": "ΓΥΜΝΑΣΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ ΕΣΠΕΡΙΝΟ", "long": 26.129116, "lat": 38.353775 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.129116, 38.353775 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686171.208737, "Y": 4247801.345465, "aa": 15163, "onoma": "2ο ΕΝΙΑΙΟ ΛΥΚΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.132558, "lat": 38.361601 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.132558, 38.361601 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686175.616517, "Y": 4247807.332267, "aa": 15144, "onoma": "2ο ΓΥΜΝΑΣΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.132610, "lat": 38.361654 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.13261, 38.361654 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686497.839566, "Y": 4247865.195934, "aa": 15302, "onoma": "ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ ΕΙΔΙΚΟ", "long": 26.136311, "lat": 38.362108 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.136311, 38.362108 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686711.220038, "Y": 4247881.353276, "aa": 15209, "onoma": "1ο ΣΕΚ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.138756, "lat": 38.362209 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.138756, 38.362209 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686707.151767, "Y": 4247883.368693, "aa": 15207, "onoma": "2ο ΤΕΕ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.138710, "lat": 38.362228 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.13871, 38.362228 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686703.695145, "Y": 4247885.398287, "aa": 15203, "onoma": "1ο ΤΕΕ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.138671, "lat": 38.362247 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.138671, 38.362247 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686654.965932, "Y": 4247917.025023, "aa": 15167, "onoma": "3ο ΕΝΙΑΙΟ ΛΥΚΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.138122, "lat": 38.362542 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.138122, 38.362542 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686654.965932, "Y": 4247917.025023, "aa": 15178, "onoma": "1ο ΕΝΙΑΙΟ ΛΥΚΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.138122, "lat": 38.362542 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.138122, 38.362542 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686300.009009, "Y": 4248087.688735, "aa": 15111, "onoma": "4ο ΓΥΜΝΑΣΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.134107, "lat": 38.364153 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.134107, 38.364153 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686551.258503, "Y": 4248102.941494, "aa": 15393, "onoma": "ΚΕΣΥΠ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.136985, "lat": 38.364238 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.136985, 38.364238 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686359.882885, "Y": 4248125.937899, "aa": 15150, "onoma": "1ο ΓΥΜΝΑΣΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.134802, "lat": 38.364485 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.134802, 38.364485 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 684887.838361, "Y": 4260691.808672, "aa": 15311, "onoma": "6ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.131517, "lat": 38.365979 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.131517, 38.365979 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 684887.838361, "Y": 4260691.808672, "aa": 15313, "onoma": "9ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.133857, "lat": 38.384268 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.133857, 38.384268 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 684887.838361, "Y": 4260691.808672, "aa": 15314, "onoma": "8ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.135080, "lat": 38.375425 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.13508, 38.375425 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 684887.838361, "Y": 4260691.808672, "aa": 15315, "onoma": "7ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.130533, "lat": 38.370493 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.130533, 38.370493 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686111.689855, "Y": 4248328.528558, "aa": 15318, "onoma": "1ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.132163, "lat": 38.365841 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.132163, 38.365841 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "X": 686817.400932, "Y": 4248207.323567, "aa": 15319, "onoma": "2ο ΔΗΜΟΤΙΚΟ ΣΧΟΛΕΙΟ ΧΙΟΥ", "long": 26.140098, "lat": 38.365023 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.140098, 38.365023 ] } }
]}];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? "I'm not sure I used it right" doesn't give answerers much to work with. What went wrong? Where are you stuck?

Comment: When i use leaflet control search it shows a point over the road i searched for. I've stuck because i can't use this point to find its closest neighbours by using leaflet knn. The project is a small app that users find the street they live in and shows the closest camp to reach in case of earthquake and the shortest path to it. @Steve Bennett

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to need to fix up the fiddle first before more of us can dig into this. You had html in your javascript section, double closing script tags, and invalid resources attempting to be loaded from the jsfiddle domain...which are invalid. You should use the external resources feature to add what you need. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/9u9r7L1o/ where I have fixed some of these problems.